# Проблема с AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Есть метод, в основном потоке он работает. Но в AsyncTask выбивает ошибку.

```
public ArrayList<String>  fillList(File dir){
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    String d ;
    //ArrayList<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(File file:files){
        if(file.isDirectory())
            fillList(file);
        else
        if(file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                int i = dir.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
                d= dir.toString().substring(i+1);

            if (Collections.frequency(myList,d)>0) {}
            else{
            myList.add(d);
            url.add(dir.toString());
            }

        }
        //hash h = new hash();
        //h.hashfol(c, url, "foldersurl");
        //h.hashfol(c,myList,"folders");
    }
    return myList;
    }
```

Там был ещё контекст, для метода hashfol,но я его убрал, все равно ошибка.
Лог

```
09-06 12:40:15.894 22005 22005 I   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.isTransitionGroup, referenced from method f.a
09-06 12:40:15.894 22005 22005 W   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5478: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.isTransitionGroup ()Z
09-06 12:40:15.894 22005 22005 D   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000c
09-06 12:40:15.894 22005 22005 I   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             Could not find method android.view.View.getTransitionName, referenced from method f.a
09-06 12:40:15.894 22005 22005 W   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5331: Landroid/view/View;.getTransitionName ()Ljava/lang/String;
09-06 12:40:15.894 22005 22005 D   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
09-06 12:40:15.901 22005 22005 W   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Landroid/app/RemoteInput;)
09-06 12:40:15.901 22005 22005 E   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             Could not find class 'android.app.RemoteInput[]', referenced from method f.a
09-06 12:40:15.901 22005 22005 W   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             VFY: unable to resolve new-array 7163 ([Landroid/app/RemoteInput;) in Lf;
09-06 12:40:15.901 22005 22005 D   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             VFY: replacing opcode 0x23 at 0x0005
09-06 12:40:15.933 22005 22005 W   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/apps/hangouts/telephony/TeleConnectionService; (744)
09-06 12:40:15.933 22005 22005 W   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/apps/hangouts/telephony/TeleConnectionService;' failed
09-06 12:40:15.933 22005 22005 E   dalvikvm com.google.android.talk             Could not find class 'com.google.and
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Не знаю в логаг ничего не понятно

Comment: Ну а вообще, этот метод можно выполнить в Async

Comment: Скорее всего где то происходит обращение к основному потокуъ

Comment: Лог абсолютно не по теме. И код некорректен, где обьявление переменной myList?